# How do I clear a specific file in the Java cache?

Tags: java, caching, jar

I would like to remove a specific cached jar file from a Java program.  Java cache behaves weirdly sometimes, and keeps loading an old jar even if a new one should be used.

The "Java Control Panel" has a ["Java Cache Viewer"](http://pscode.org/player.jnlp) feature that allows us to see cached jar files.

[image: The Java Cache Viewer]

I was wondering if there was a way to detect a cached jar file but directly from a java program, and then remove that file.  Is there an API allowing that?

Comment: Can I ask why do you want to clear those specific cache files?

Comment: Java cache behaves weirdly sometimes, and keep loading an old jar even if a new one should be used. It's to avoid situations like that

Comment: Are you the one deploying the application?  Is it a standard embedded applet, or an app. launched using Java Web Start?

Comment: No, i'm not the one deploying the application. It's a standard embedded applet, no JNLP used here

Comment: I am now taking the time to add what I ended up doing: com.sun.deploy.cache.Cache & com.sun.deploy.cache.CacheEntry provide very useful methods to do what I wanted to do at that time.

Answer (score 2):

Yes! I've just found a solution to this problem. There's a command line statement "javaws" that let's you handle specific java-related actions. You can type javaws into your console/terminal and it'll give you options but to remove a specific application, you could add this to your code:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javaws -uninstall <jnlp file>");
```

where  can be the file or a url.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

See http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/plugin/developer_guide/applet_caching.html for ways to control the cache.

Comment: *"cache only is for applets"*  Wrong.  Applets **and** web start applications.  The cache can be found in the [Java Cache Viewer](http://pscode.org/player.jnlp) of the Java Control Panel.  I'll add an edit to the main question to show the cache viewer.  Please edit your answer to avoid me needing to vote it down.

Comment: Isn´t it supposed that sometimes we haven´t really clear the way these technologies work? Why an advertence? :O